# ImageView in Listview throwing Exception in Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to include the list view in tabs layout which include two texts and a image view. but it is giving following log cat. There are three tabs in my app out of which I am trying to include the listview in second and third tab. The second tab was working earlier but as I pasted the same code for the third tab with some changes it is showing following erroe The last return statement of the tab is throwing exception .I searched for similar questions but didn't got the answer. I am new at android development .

StackTrace log

```
         Process: com.example.shubham.tabexample, PID: 32353
                                                                            android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                            Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.shubham.tabexample:id/imgview with resource ID #0x7f0e0094
                                                                            Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.shubham.tabexample:id/imgview" (7f0e0094) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0e0094}
                                                                                at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:691)
                                                                                at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:575)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:972)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:931)
                                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:167)
                                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:155)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1026)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1083)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:192)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                at com.example.shubham.JeevanSathi.Activity.Tab2.onCreateView(Tab2.java:28)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2034)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1239)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1087)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1613)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:825)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:511)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6286)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:713)
07-29 13:10:38.399 32353-32353/com.example.shubham.tabexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:785)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1080)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6286)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6286)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6286)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6286)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6286)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:714)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20110)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2649)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1586)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7009)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6293)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1065)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

Tab2.java

```
                    package com.example.shubham.JeevanSathi.Activity;

                /**
                 * Created by Shubham on 7/25/2017.
                 */

                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
                import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.ViewGroup;

                import com.example.shubham.JeevanSathi.R;



                //Our class extending fragment
                public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

                    //Overriden method onCreateView
                    @Override
                    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                        //Returning the layout file after inflating
                        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
                        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: show java class

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.shubham.tabexample:id/imgview" (7f0e0094) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0e0094}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your drawable file if it is available then clean the code and build it. If it will not help post the xml file here